# Do not reformat JSX destructuring code style in pre-commit in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webstorm, jsx

I use this option:

[image]

Before reformat:
[image]

After reformat:
[image]

What settings do I need to leave code like in *before*?

Comment: prettify settings/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow [WEB-29268](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29268) for updates.

For now, I can only suggest disabling **Align when multiline** in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript | Wrapping and Braces | Function declaration parameters**.